# How to store aggregation pipeline in mongoDB?

Tags: python, mongodb, rule-engine

I am developing a rule engine using MongoDB and Python. I want to store Rules in MongoDB in a Rule database "myrulesdb" and want to use it to run aggregation pipeline on a different collection. Rule saved in MongoDB is

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("57f46e843166d426a20d5e08"),
"Rule" : "[{\"$match\":{\"Name.First\":\"Sunil\"}},{\"$limit\":5}]",
"Description" : "You live long life"
}
```

Python Code:

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)

db = client['myDB']
coll = db['myColl']

ruledb = client['myrulesdb']
rulecoll = ruledb['myrules']

rule1 = rulecoll.find_one({}, {"Rule":1, "_id":0})

pipe = rule1['Rule']
print(pipe)

data = coll.aggregate(pipeline=pipe)
```

I am getting correct string when i print pipe.

```
[{"$match":{"Name.First":"Sunil"}},{"$limit":5}]
```

But when i pass this to aggregate() function, it gives me following error:

```
data = coll.aggregate(pipeline=pipe)
in aggregate raise TypeError("pipeline must be a list")
TypeError: pipeline must be a list
```

After retrieving pipeline from database, how can i pass it to aggregate() function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why you are doing this but the culprit here is the value of the `Rule` field which is string. If you try a little debuging with the `print()` function your will see that `type(pipe)` yields `<class 'str'>`

You can fix this by loading the value using [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) like this:

```
>>> import json
>>> r = {"Rule" : "[{\"$match\":{\"Name.First\":\"Sunil\"}},{\"$limit\":5}]"}
>>> pipe = json.loads(r['Rule'])
>>> pipe
[{'$match': {'Name.First': 'Sunil'}}, {'$limit': 5}]
>>> type(pipe)
<class 'list'>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a late answer (but maybe useful for others looking at this question) and only in case you might consider using **Java** instead of Python. Please disregard my answer if not.
You can use the small free library https://github.com/MongoPipe/mongopipe-core to do the pipeline saving, parameterized running, automatic migration, etc.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).