# Pipeline must be list Airflow

Tags: python, mongodb, list, airflow

writing a DAG in airflow to extract sum of balance but getting error

```
import logging
import json
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

from datetime import datetime
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from airflow import AirflowException
# Connection

from airflow.providers.mongo.hooks.mongo import MongoHook

def wallet_bal():
   hook = MongoHook(mongo_conn_id='mongo_default')
   client = hook.get_conn()
   print(f"** Connected to MongoDB **- {client.server_info()}")
   db = client.test
   
   query = db.wallets.aggregate([{'$group': {'_id': None, 'count': {'$sum': '$balance.value'}}}])
   
   wallets_collection = db.aggregate("wallets", query=query)
   logger.info(wallets_collection)
   
   logger.info("HI SEE THE PIPELINE")
   return 'MONGO DATA TO CONNECT'



dag = DAG('WALLET_DAGS', description='Mongo 
Viewer',schedule_interval=None,start_date=datetime(2017, 3, 20), catchup=False)

connect_case_mongo = PythonOperator(task_id='test_wallet', python_callable=wallet_bal, dag=dag)

connect_case_mongo
```

getting same error again & again after so many diffrent changes

```
TypeError: pipeline must be a list
[2022-11-28, 11:24:51 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1401} INFO - Marking task as FAILED. dag_id=WALLET_DAGS, task_id=test_wallet, execution_date=20221128T112443, start_date=20221128T112449, end_date=20221128T112451
```

Tried different scenarios but not able to convert it in list i already have seen previous stack results

Comment: Hey Shiva! Can you post your entire error? Usually you get more lines of exception trace. I can better help you with your issue.

Comment: did I answer question below? If so, you can mark it with the green checkmark as answer. If not, let me know if I can be of further help

Answer (score 0):

my best guess of where your error lies is in either of the two 'aggregate' calls. That is, one/both of these lines has a bug:

```
   query = db.wallets.aggregate([{'$group': {'_id': None, 'count': {'$sum': '$balance.value'}}}])
   
   wallets_collection = db.aggregate("wallets", query=query)
```

I googled your error and found some related questions that confirm this error has nothing to do with Airflow and it is a MongoDB error. There seems to be a bug with your 'aggregate' function call(s). Make sure to look at the MongoDB [docs](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/database.html#pymongo.database.Database.aggregate) for the 'aggregate' method. It must take a 'pipeline' argument which is of type `Sequence[Mapping[str, Any]]`. Your first call seems to be correct as 'pipeline' argument is of type List which is type-casted to the required Sequence type I believe.

Your second aggregate call, however, seems to have an issue. Your first argument which gets taken as the 'pipeline' argument is of type string (i.e. "wallets"). This is wrong as'pipeline' parameter is of type `Sequence[Mapping[str, Any]]` NOT of type string.

You might want to look at this related question: [How to store aggregation pipeline in mongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39865416/how-to-store-aggregation-pipeline-in-mongodb)

In short, I'd advice to ensure that your aggregate arguments are of correct type.